# Mongoose es6 promises, exec callback

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm not sure I get the difference and the benefits switching from classic mongoose callbacks and ES6 promises.
This aggregate query

```
router.get('/', function(req,res) {
caseNote.aggregate([
        {$unwind: '$field'},
        {$match: {field: "aaa"}},
        {$project: {field: 1, _id: 0}}
    ])
    .exec(function(err, data) {
        if (err)
            res.json(err);
        else {
            if(data[0])
                res.json(data[0].field);
            else
                res.json([]);
        }
    });
});
```

with some ES6 sugar would be turned in

```
router.get('/', cache, function(req,res) {
    caseNote.aggregate([
        {$unwind: '$field'},
        {$match: {field: "aaa"}},
        {$project: {field: 1, _id: 0}}
    ])
        .exec()
        .then(data => res.json(data[0] ? data[0].field: {error:"result error"}))
        .catch(err => res.json(err) );

});
```

why I would prefer the `then() & catch()` brothers instead of the `exec()` callback?

Answer (score 0):

Code becomes cleaner and more readable with ES6 promises since you can take advantage of the `catch()` method and handle errors in one single block of code.

In this specific example I do not see much of a difference since there are no multiple callbacks.

This is a great article that goes much more into detail.

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch3.md

Comment: I will read the whole repo, thanks. In meantime, a side-question: does ES6 Generators are going to be 'overtaken' by Promises or they have different purposes?

Comment: Well, generators have many different uses, but actually, I think it will be the other way around, since ES7 async functions are based on generators. This is a really good read as well! http://rossboucher.com/await/#/